# ion-back-button is not showing up in toolbar in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm trying to show a back button in the toolbar of one page.
Below is excerpt of my code.

```
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button [text]="" [icon]="arrow-back"> </ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

If I set the  `defaultHref` attribute, it works but I will not have ability to use my custom back button with *text* and *icon*.

```
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"> </ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

How do I make it work. Could anyone please help?

Comment: How are you navigating to this page? Is the routerDirection set to 'forward' or 'root' ?

Comment: @PankajSati I was using this `router.navigate(['about'])`

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to use a custom header (like me), this is the workaround that I found pretty easy to implement and works like it's supposed to.

`/components/custom-header.html`

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>Page title</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

And the usage will be like:

`/pages/home-page.html`

```
<ion-header>
    <custom-header>
       <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </custom-header>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: ps: I did it this way because I found out that at least the `ion-header` and `ion-back-button` needs to be declared on the same page component file `home-page.html` (in the case of this example). I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: This worked for me. Is it a bug in Ionic or is there some underlying reason why we can't put the back button in a separate component template?

Comment: @WillTaylor I'm not very sure why we can't use it in a separate component. But at the top of my head, when I was battling with this, I thought maybe custom components are not aware of the navigations states or something similar. Like I said, I'm not very sure. In any case, I'm glad it works for you and thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is working in my project ..**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button text=""></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>About</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: @scriobh Have you removed **`[icon]="arrow-back"`** from **`ion-back-button`** tag ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on the github page about the fact that ion-back-button won't display in non ion-header containers such as custom components. However, you can work around this with css.

```
.can-go-back ion-back-button {
    display: block;
}
```

GitHub issue open since 2019: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17039

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as yours, I have managed to remove the `<ion-back-button>` and made a custom button like this:

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/home">
            <ion-img src='path-to-your.png'></ion-img>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-text>About</ion-text>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Then adjust the style. A little bit of work but it's worth it.

Comment: The problem going with this approach is, we won't be able to get the smooth animation that it gives when hit on the back button ( Per docs, when used [ion-back-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button) ).
I tried this and it works fine but I lost the animation.
`<ion-buttons slot="start" (click)="onBackPressed()">
      <ion-icon class="back-icon" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>`

Answer (score -1):

i find it works cleaner this way..by using the same ion-button but with an icon inside..its cleaner this way and works just normal..all you need to do is change the route to the previous route

```
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-buttons slot="start" routerLink="/payment">
      <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" class="xdsffdd"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-buttons>
```